# change/edit FASTA headers

Tags: fasta, awk

I have a FASTA file with 97,000 entires arranged like this :

```
>tr|A0A075B6G3|A0A075B6G3_HUMAN Dystrophin OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=DMD PE=1 SV=1
```

I want to have an output like this:

```
>A0A075B6G3|1|training
```

I am aware of many one liners in `sed`, `perl` and `awk` but none are working . I have something like this :

```
awk '/>/{$0=">ID|1|training"}1'
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Where is the `|1|` coming from? Is that an incrementing value that will change for each line? Is it the `PE=1`? Or maybe the `SV=1`?

Answer (score 7):

One way using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } /^>/ { print ">" $2, "1", "training"; next }1' file.fa
```

This sets the [*field separator* (FS)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html) and the [*output field separator* (OFS)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html)  to a pipe character. Then for each header line, we can just print the fields we want. The output fields will be delimited with pipe characters since we already set `OFS` to a pipe character in the `BEGIN` block. We can use [*next*](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html) here to force awk to immediately stop processing the current record and move on to the next record, which is just the next line, since, by default, awk's [*record separator*](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/awk-split-records.html) is a newline character.

Since the `1` on the end just returns true, it performs the default action, which is to print the current record stored in `$0`. It is just the same as:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } /^>/ { print ">" $2, "1", "training"; next } { print $0 }'
```

Which is the same as:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } /^>/ { print ">" $2, "1", "training"; next } { print }'
```

Comment: Thank you @ Steve.

Comment: Nice! You could shorten it to something like `awk -F'|' '/>/{printf ">%s|1|training\n",$2; next}1' file.fa` or even `awk -F'|' '{ (/>/) ? $0=">"$2"|1|training" : $0=$0}1' file.fa` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -p -i -e 's/>[a-z]+?\|([A-Z]+[^\|]+?\|).*SV=([0-9]+)/>$1$2\|training/g' myfilename.fa
```

Not tested yet. Just check the sequence ID starts with a capital A-Z character. Probably wise to test it without the `-i`

Comment: Many thanks @M_

Comment: Thanks @user1738234 , I'll test it later. I assume that the `1` refers to the SV number. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another simple perl solution:

```
$ perl -lpe 's/\|.*(\d+)/|$1|training/ if s/>.+?\|/>/' file.fa 
>A0A075B6G3|1|training
```

Note that you didn't tell us where the `1` came from, so I am taking the last numbers on the line, the `SV=1` in your case. If you want to hard-code the `1`, you can do so easily with:

```
perl -lpe 's/\|.*/|1|training/ if s/>.+?\|/>/' file.fa
```

The `-lpe` options mean "**p**rint each line, adding a new**l**ine character to each `print` call, after applying the script given by `-e`". So this will read the file line by line, do its thing and print the result.

The `s/old/new/` is the substitution operator and will replace `old` with `new`. In this case, we are replacing a `|` character (`\|`) and everything after it (`.*`) until the last set of numbers on the line which we capture and save as `$1` with `(\d+)`. This substitution will only happen if we have already successfully substituted the leading `>` and everything until the first `|` (`>.+?\|`) with just a `>`.

If you want to edit the original file in place, use the `-i` flag (but give it a value, `.bak` in the example below, since that ensures a backup file with the original data and that extension will be created):

```
perl -i .bak -lpe 's/\|.*(\d+)/|$1|training/ if s/>.+?\|/>/' file.fa
```